# Where can I find Firefox 5 .deb packages for Debian Wheezy (testing)?

Tags: firefox, debian, packages, debian-wheezy

I'd like to install Firefox 5 for Debian Wheezy (testing). Where can I find suitable .deb packages (unofficial is fine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the official [Debian Mozilla team](http://mozilla.debian.net/).

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I had seen that page somewhere (in fact, it was in my sources.list for a different version).  But mysteriously, it wasn't linked from the [Iceweasel](http://wiki.debian.org), [Mozilla](http://wiki.debian.org/Mozilla), or [Firefox](http://wiki.debian.org/Firefox) wiki pages.

Comment: I've added it to the Iceweasel and Firefox pages.

Comment: It's now available in Experimental.